# Pandas обновить сводную таблицу (Pivot table)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

есть Pivot файл, Ссылка: [TransFiles.ru/os4r7](https://TransFiles.ru/os4r7)  в Sheet2 хранятся данные, которые переодически дополняются из других источников [image: Sheet2] 
В Sheet1 создана сводная таблица, на основе данных из Sheet2
[image: Sheet1]
проблема заключается в том, что перед тем, как исползовать данные, приходиться вручную обновлять таблицу в Sheet1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос: возможно ли обновить таблицу в Sheet1 посредством Pandas или Openpyxl?

Comment: спасибо, что поделились своим горем. мы сочувствуем.

Comment: Ни примера данных, ни собственно вопроса. Что вы от нас хотите - непонятно. Видимо, и правда сочувствия. )

Comment: прошу прощения, исправил вопрос, добавил данные

Comment: Ну так то сводная таблица легко считается в `Pandas`: `df.groupby('No.')['QTY'].sum()`, но вот чтобы её прямо в нужный вид привести и поместить на лист - это надо разбираться.